# Is there any way to pushd without enter that directory?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, cd, pushd

```
ls
// a b c
```

So,with pushd,i want to add 'b' to the directory stack index ,but not enter directory b, is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: https://medium.com/@kishankr.maurya/directory-management-using-cd-vs-pushd-6af9c96732e4

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-n` parameter of `pushd`:

```
pushd -n somedir
```

`-n` will cause directory `somedir` to be added to the stack, while suppressing the normal change of directory.

You can see the documentation for `pushd` with:

```
man bash
```

Then search for `pushd` by issuing (multiple times):

```
/pushd
```

Comment: You can also get the 'pushd' documentation by running `help pushd` at the Bash prompt.